# Get tweet by location with tweet4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I want to get the tweet in Hanoi.

1) I have use the search query but I receive duplicate tweet,how to avoid that?

```
Query query = new Query(queryString);
       GeoLocation city = new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude);
       query.geoCode(city, 20, "mi");
```

2) What is tweetID? Is it increase by time?Can I use `query.setSinceId();` with the maxID from last retrive?

3) I try other way by use the stream to get Tweet but its receive tweet not in area I want(ex: from china or Laos) Am I was wrong?

```
 double lat = 21.082647;
 double lon = 105.822526;
 double lon1 = lon - 0.05;
 double lon2 = lon + 0.05;
 double lat1 = lat - 0.05;
 double lat2 = lat + 0.05;
 double box[][] = {{lon1, lat1}, {lon2, lat2}};
 fq.locations(box);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's API searches for geotagged tweets first and falls back to the users profile location if a tweet isn't explicitly geotagged.  This could be the reason your search is returning tweets from locations outside your boundary.

For example:

Suppose your searching Hanoi's geolocation for tweets containing a query.  The search will return explicitly geotagged tweets from Hanoi containing the query.  The search will also return tweets from a different geolocation containing the query by users with a profile location of Hanoi.

Answer (score 0):

The [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) doesn't seem what you're looking for because it only returns relevant tweets (recent and popular). If you want to get a complete list of tweets then you'll need the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview).

After you put in your lat/long you will get some tweets outside the area you want (it's only a few) which you you can filter through post-processing. At least at this point you're getting a more complete list than the Search API.

I'm not sure how many you're getting from China or Laos, but you can always refine your boundaries to restrict it to Hanoi. I belive the ones you have are a little too small +/- .05 is not large maybe `105.76,20.96,105.94,21.1` might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your filter is wrong.Restrict more so you can find the solution